# How to do this MongoDB query using java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have to write a simple `MongoDB` query using `java` but am not able to do it.

The mongo query looks like this:

```
db.yourCollection.find({"$where" : "this.startDate < this.endDate"})
```

I have to write the above query using the `QueryBuilder` class. But am not able to do it in `MongoDB` `java` driver.

```
BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
document.put("id", 1001);
document.put("intValue", 1200);
document.put("updateValue", 2100);

DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start("intValue").lessThan("updateValue").get();
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
System.out.println("Result : -"+cursor.next());}
```

The above code does not return any results. But if changed to `updateValue` into `2100` it is giving result. My question here is `lessThan` takes object as input parameter. Then how can I pass document field as an input parameter?

Answer (score 14):

Ideally your mongoDB query should be like this: -

```
db.yourCollection.find({"startDate": {$lt: endDate}})
```

which can be written in Java like this: -

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("startDate", new BasicDBObject("$lt", endDate);
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
```

You can take a look at [Official Tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial)

---

If you want to use [QueryBuilder](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.2/com/mongodb/QueryBuilder.html), you can do it like this: -

```
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start("startDate").lessThan("endDate").get();
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
```

Comment: The above query builder is not working. if the "endDate" is a field in the same document. It is working if i give the constant value instead of endDate in the QueryBuilder. Moreover the BasicDBObject doesn't accept the endDate field name in thje second parameter

Answer (score 5):

QueryBuilder helps construct complex queries to retrieve data from a collection in mongo db.
You can use the QueryBuilder like this.

```
BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
QueryBuilder qb = new QueryBuilder();
qb.or(new QueryBuilder().put("starting_date").is(null).put("ending_date").is(null).get(),
                new QueryBuilder().put("starting_date").lessThanEquals("ending_date").get());
document.putAll(qb.get());
DBCursor cursor = getDbCollection().find(document)
```

- QueryBuilder qb = new QueryBuilder(), instantiates a new QueryBuilder.
- The logic build by the QueryBuilder in the example above is;  (starting date = null and ending date = null) or (starting date <=ending date)
- document.putAll(qb.get()) adds the logic constructed to the DBObject.